# How to change from self hosting nancy to under iis

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, web, nancy

I created a nancy self hosting web app (with razor).

Now I want to move it to a website under IIS on a windows server.
I was given the name I should call it in IIS. 
What are my options?  What's the easiest way to port/move/point to it? 
How do I set the name of the website? Do I do that in IIS or in the app. 
(The self hosting Nancy has a url under localhost... and it sets the port number)

I have no experience in deploying to IIS, or deploying websites, so please also point me to a link for that when you answer.

Comment: I understand that OWin is not too much of an option. 

Even though there is http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline that would be too much hassle. 

So my question is now: Fastest and easiest way to change my Nancy app from Nancy self hosting to IIS hosting.

Comment: I ended up - after discussing on the NancyFX chat, copying everything to a Nancy ASP.Net hosted project.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up - after discussing on the NancyFX chat, copying everything to a new Nancy ASP.Net hosted project.

I thought it would be some easy configuration change and NUGET package change, but it seems that is a rather daunting task...